# Text next to Swatch on Layered navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, configurable-swatches

Magento 1.9.3

Is it possible to get the name of the configurable swatch next to the swatch box in the layered navigation?
EG.

[ ] White (1)

Currently its just [ ] (1) and you can hover for the name of the swatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, copy the following template file:

`/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/configurableswatches/catalog/layer/filter/swatches.phtml`

To your own theme so that you can modify it:

`/app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/configurableswatches/catalog/layer/filter/swatches.phtml`

Then add the following line inside the anchor link tags (`<a>`) where you'd like to output the swatch label:

```
<?php echo $_label; ?>
```

Example (Comment included with added line `<!-- -->`):

```
<li<?php if ($_hasImage){ echo ' style="line-height: ' . $_lineHeight . 'px;"'; } ?>>
    <?php if ($_hasItems): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>" class="<?php echo $_linkClass ?>">
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="<?php echo $_linkClass ?>">
    <?php endif; ?>
        <span class="swatch-label"<?php if ($_hasImage){ echo ' style="' . $_linkCss . '"'; } ?>>
            <?php if ($_hasImage): ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $_swatchUrl; ?>" alt="<?php echo $_label; ?>" title="<?php echo $_label ?>" width="<?php echo $_swatchInnerWidth ?>" height="<?php echo $_swatchInnerHeight ?>" />
                <span><?php echo $_label; ?></span> <!-- Here is where I am outputting the label of each color swatch -->
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $_label; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </span>
        <?php if ($this->shouldDisplayProductCount()): ?>
            <span class="count">(<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)</span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($_hasItems): ?>
        </a>
    <?php else: ?>
        </span>
    <?php endif; ?>
</li>
```

Once you get the label outputting to the page, you'll likely need to modify CSS styles to make it look good.